# Reversing a formula (javascript function)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have this function to get x and y coordinates from latitude and longitude and the width and height of a map:

```
export const latLon2xy = (lat, lon, width, height) => {
    const scale = {x: 1.5, y: 0.5}
    const offset = {x: 0,   y: 0}
    const x = (width * (180 + lon) / 360) % (scale.x * width)
    const rad = lat * Math.PI / 180
    const merc = scale.y * Math.log((1 + Math.sin(rad)) / (1 - Math.sin(rad)))
    const y = (height * merc / (2 * Math.PI))
    return {x: x + offset.x, y: y * -1 + height / 2 + offset.y}
}
```

But now I need to reverse it to get latitude and longitude by inputting x and y as well as width and height.

Can anyone help me to reverse this formula?

I know this is not a standard stackexchange format question but I still hope someone can help.

Comment: [Reverse math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) is a specific subfield of mathematical logic - I've retagged.